# Moving from HDF5 to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, hdf5, h5py

I have a many large 1-D hdf5 datasets with next properties:

- init size = (5201,),
- maxshape = (6000000,),
- dtype ='float32'
- chunks = (10000,)
- compression = "gzip"
- Path example: file["Group"]["1"]["Group1"]["2"]["Dataset"]

I want to move them into the PostgreSQL, I dealed with structure of database and inserting data, but each filling takes ~650 seconds of 72,4mb hdf5 file, can someone give me a tips/advice how I can improve the performance?

What I have now:

```
def fill_database(self, dog):
    if isinstance(dog, h5py.Dataset):
        name = dog.name.split('/')
        table_name = '{}_{}'.format(name[3], name[5]) 
        data = dog.value.astype(int).tolist()
        self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (cur_id INT PRIMARY KEY , data INT[]);'.format(table_name))
        self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s, %s)'.format(table_name), (name[2], data))

        if isinstance(dog, h5py.Group):
            for k, v in dict(dog).items():
                self.fill_database(v)
```

What I tried:

```
import psycopg2
import h5py
from itertools import islice


with h5py.File('full_db.hdf5') as hdf5file:
    with psycopg2.connect(database='hdf5', user='postgres', password='pass', port=5432) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('drop table if EXISTS mytable;')
        cur.execute('create table mytable (data INT[]);')
        chunksize = 10000
        t = iter(hdf5file["Group"]["1"]["Group1"]["2"]["Dataset"][:].astype(int))
        rows = islice(t, chunksize)
        while rows:
            statement = "INSERT INTO mytable(data) VALUES {}".format(rows) # I stuck here
            cur.execute(statement)
            rows = islice(t, chunksize)
        conn.commit()
```

Also I tried to do something with LIMIT in PostgreSQL and many other ways but I was not successful.

I think some of the problem may be because of arrays in the database, I use them for later more convenient output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After almost two weeks I think I can answer my own question. 
In search of an answer, I came across on the Internet at this page https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/179
Also after reading of documentation, I understood that a copying from a file works even quicker and I tried to use the module of StringIO. And thats what I get:

```
import h5py
import psycopg2
import time
from io import StringIO

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='hdf5', user='postgres', password=' ')
cur = conn.cursor()

file = h5py.File('db.hdf5', 'r')
data_set = file['path/to/large/data_set'].value.astype(int).tolist()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_test;')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE table_test (data INTEGER[]);')

# ORIGINAL
start = time.time()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO table_test VALUES (%s);', (data_set,))
print('Original: {} sec'.format(round(time.time() - start, 2)))

# STRING FORMAT
start = time.time()
data_str = ','.join(map(str, data_set)).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO table_test VALUES (ARRAY[{}]);'.format(data_str))
print('String format: {} sec'.format(round(time.time() - start, 2)))

# STRING IO COPY
start = time.time()
data_str = ','.join(map(str, data_set)).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')
data_io = StringIO('{{{}}}'.format(data_str))
cur.copy_from(data_io, 'table_test')
print('String IO: {} sec'.format(round(time.time() - start, 2)))

conn.commit()
```

Which gives me next result with dataset with shape (1200201,):

```
Original: 1.27 sec
String format: 0.58 sec
String IO: 0.3 sec
```